# Remove newline on separate print statements

Tags: python

Here's an example on what I'm trying to achieve :

```
print("Hi!")
print("Hello!")
>> Hi! Hello!
```

Whats really happening :

```
print("Hi!")
print("Hello!")
>> Hi!
>> Hello!
```

I've tried stuff like `sep=" "` and `print("Hi!"),` but those didn't work.

Please don't mark this as duplicate since all the answers for this question don't work for my situation.

https://pastebin.com/57xyqb8C : For my full code.

Comment: `print('Hi!', end='')` This removes the new line at the end of the string.

Comment: You've not clearly shown that the answers in the duplicate don't work and the answers below are all the same, so I'm closing this. `sep` is only used when there are multiple arguments to the print function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this solves your problem:

```py
print("Hi!", end='')
print("Hello!")

Hi! Hello!
```

Answer (score 3):

The `end` keyword is used for this in python. You could have any value for it:

```
print("Hi!", end=' ')
print("Hello!")

>>> Hi! Hello!

print("Hi!", end = ' This is a string \n')
print("Hello!")

>>> Hi! This is a string 
>>> Hello!
```